# Manga about a sword that only a little boy can unsheath

Tags: hero-tales

What is that manga that is set in the 17th century about a small boy who has a sword from his deceased old man that only he can open when he's angry? The sword is longer than his body.

And he's all about revenge and the manga is often about war tactic or strategy...

Chosen people have star marks on their bodies and that boy is one of the star-marked people...

Comment: Sounds a bit like D.Gray-Man.

Comment: But Allen Walker (D.Gray-Man) doesn't wield any huge swords? I would also not consider him as a little boy.

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for *[Hero Tales](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hero_Tales)* aka *Juushin Enbu.* There's also a 26 episode anime adaptation of it.

From [ANN](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=8281):

> Set in a time of chaos, seven heroes of the Stars, the Hokushintenkun, rise up to lead the people. Two of the seven, the Nitenshinson, the Hagun and the Tanrou, are never supposed to exist at the same time, but fate has decided otherwise. Taito, chosen as the Hagun, now must rise up to defeat the Tanrou, as the fate of the Stars destined it to be.

[image: Dat pose!]

Answer (score 1):

I am kind of sure you mean Juushin enbu. Its by the same mangaka as full metal Alchemist with the same kind of art.

Comment: nope... that's not it~~~ it have some echi on it, and the kid are around 8-9 years old...

Comment: and the art is much more serious...

Comment: and the strategy part is just super!!

Comment: it was in jump comic

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_series_run_in_Weekly_Sh%C5%8Dnen_Jump
If you think you may recognise the name then there's a list. I think searching with character names would narrow it down. 
~cheers